# Symfony5 cannot deploy code to the server, permission issue

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, server, symfony5

I am attempting to deploy my Symfony production code to an Ubuntu server.

I have everything set up and I can deploy fine if I set the permissions to the web folder to 777, but if I try to set it to 755, git cannot write to the folder.

I have done the following:

```
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/website/
 sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/website/
```

But I get a failed to write files notice from git.

Now if I change the permissions to 777, it works fine.

If I ls -la, this is what I get:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 17 19:19 website
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the user that you are logged in a member of the `www-data` group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need to make your user a member of the `www-data` group.

```sh
$ usermod -a -G $USER www-data
```

or run `git` as the `www-data` user.

```sh
$ sudo -u www-data git ...
```